# Gulp uglify - ignore function rename for specific functions

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

I have some functions in my module which injects the function code to the page within script tags. e.g. if i have a following function.

```
var test = function test() {alert("hello world")}
```

and then I have to inject that function as code to page e.g.

```
document.write("<script">);
document.write(test.toString());
document.write("</script">);
```

Now the problem is that when gulp/uglify task runs; it uglifies the code that means it rename function names and moremore. in this case truncate the function name and make it anonymous function instead; which results in function code (toString) being injected to the page without having a function name.

One solution I think is that I can may be disable function names renaming in uglify however that would apply to the whole scripts and it won't rename functions at all which dosen't seems to be appropriate. Or to set mangle as false!

I would appreciate some quick help/thoughts about this.
Thank you.

I am using following code to run the gulp task.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
gp_concat = require('gulp-concat'),
gp_rename = require('gulp-rename'),
gp_uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('js-fef', function(){
return gulp.src(['file1.js', 'file2.js', 'file3.js'])
    .pipe(gp_concat('concat.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe(gp_rename('uglify.js'))
    .pipe(gp_uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['js-fef'], function(){});var gulp = require('gulp'),
```

Comment: You could put your `var test = ...` in a seperate file then pipe another concat after the uglify.  So your process would go like this `concat normal files --> uglify --> concat with test.js --> done`